# Input format using scanf

Tags: c

I can't solve this problem found in a C textbook:

Input data using the following scanf function, so that a=10, b=20, c1='A', c2='a', x=1.5, y=-3.75, z= 67.8. What do you type on the keyboard?

```
scanf("%5d%5d%c%c%f%f%*f,%f",&a,&b,&c1,&c2,&x,&y,&z);
```

Basically it's a question about the input format in C. I tried typing the following, but it didn't work:

```
00010凵00020Aa凵1.5凵-3.75凵1.5,凵67.8
```

where 凵 represent a space. When I use printf to output the variables, it gives the following error message:

Unhandled exception at 0x000007FEEC8243CE (msvcr120d.dll) in Project1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000ACCCCCCCC.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: What's wrong with `scanf("%d %d %c %c %f %f %f", ...);`? Your input would then be `10 20 A a 1.5 3.75 67.8`.

Comment: Well, it's a question at the end of a Chapter in a C textbook. The purpose of the question is to test the students' familiarity with C scanf specs. That's why it's deliberately made so complicated. Of course I know the best way to do it is just your suggestion, but that's not the point. The point is, how do you solve this problem designed by this retard?

Comment: If the question is designed to test the student's familiarity, why are you asking us to solve the problem? We're not the student. If the book hasn't provided you with the necessary information, contact the author or buy a different book.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much! Really appreciate your help and your attitude. Now, leave me alone.

Comment: No need for that, @KenWhite is trying to give good advice. If you work at it you will come out a better coder.

Comment: It's a very poor idea to get rude with people you're asking for free help to solve your problem. You may want to keep that in mind. Also keep in mind that when you post here, you do not get to pick and choose who responds or comments on your post. Unless your book is on the subject of *How to learn to copy/paste the work of others instead of doing it yourself*, you should learn to solve problems on your own.

Comment: @FalloutRanger: The input you posted works perfectly fine with the `scanf` format you posted. No need to change anything. As for the "unhandled exception" error, it has nothing to do with what you posted so far. There's no way to say what's going on in your code and why it "didn't work" until you show the rest of it.

Comment: @AnT is correct: http://ideone.com/ZWEOAy Please un-accept my answer so i can delete it.

Comment: @AnT Thank you I will check it out tomorrow, since I don't have access to Visual Studio now.

Comment: @Ben, no need for that, thank you for your help. Appreciate it!

Comment: @FalloutRanger No, please do, the answer is irrelevant and should be removed.

Comment: @FalloutRanger: My educated guess would be that you copy-pasted the `scanf` format string to `printf` and transferred the `*` character as well. `*` in `printf` formats means something very very different from `scanf` formats. It could easily make your `printf` to crash.

Comment: @Ben As you wish :)

Answer (score 3):

The input you posted works perfectly fine with the `scanf` format you posted. No need to change anything. As for the "unhandled exception" error, it has nothing to do with what you posted so far. There's no way to say what's going on in your code and why it "didn't work" until you show the rest of it.

My "educated guess" would be that you just copy-pasted the `scanf` format string to `printf`, thus thoughtlessly transferring the `%*f` format specifier to `printf` as well. However, `*` in `printf` format string means something [completely different](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf#Parameters) from `scanf` format string. It will typically make your `printf` to crash, unless you make some very deliberate changes in the variadic part of `printf` argument list.

P.S. BTW, there's no need to pad the first two integeres with leading zeros. That `5` in the format string simply *limits the maximum* number of characters to read, it does not impose any minimum. You can just use `"10 20Aa 1.5 3.75 1.5, 67.8"`.

Comment: For P.S +1 . I was going to test it.

Comment: Do you know html?